# How to implement this GUI list in java swing

Tags: java, swing, tree

I want to create an option list when my user hover over the button mouse pointer becomes hand pointer and a line shows underneath the word, How can I implement this in java swing?
Here some code I tried

```
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[20];
    buttons [0] = new JButton("Option 1");
    buttons [0].setOpaque(true);
    buttons [0].setRolloverEnabled(true);
    buttons [0].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    buttons [0].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseEntered(e);
            buttons [0].setFocusPainted(true);
            buttons [0].setFocusable(true);
            buttons [0].setContentAreaFilled(true);
            buttons [0].setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }
        
    });
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like a jtree https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

Comment: It(the image) looks like tree. Is it what you are trying to implement?

Comment: I tried to use JTree but its look very ugly and not the same as in the photo

Comment: *"its look very ugly"* The look of a `JTree` is very adjustable. Do the tutorial.  See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for a 'pretty' tree (IMO). And a tip: Add @FastSnail (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 2):

thi is an example, try this

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  public class InputDialogWithDropdownListbox {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
  String[] choices = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
  String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose now...",
   "The Choice of a Lifetime", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, // Use
                                                                    //                         default
                                                                    // icon
    choices, // Array of choices
    choices[1]); // Initial choice
   System.out.println(input);
 }
  }
```